# Heroku Flask App Deployment: Continuous H14 Failure Message (No Web Processes Running)

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to deploy a python flask app on Heroku but I am continuously getting an H14 (no web processes running) error. Here is a look at my log:

```
2021-07-17T03:02:17.638037+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running ..."
```

I have tried `ps:scale web=1` but I also continuously get the following error:

```
Scaling dynos... !
▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).
```

My build log:

```
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Using cached install of python-3.9.6
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
...
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 361.4M
remote: -----> Launching...
...
```

When I run `heroku ps`:

`No dynos on ⬢ <project-name>`

Procfile (yes, with a capital P):

`web:gunicorn main:app`

I am completely puzzled at this point. If anyone can offer any help, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

-teleriffr

Comment: your Procfile should be `web: gunicorn main:app` , space between `:` and `gunicorn`

Comment: @charchit Thank you so much! This fix solved by H14 error! I am still getting an H10 error because I haven't installed one of my packages with conda, but this got me past the H14 error! I appreciate your help greatly!

Answer (score 0):

Big ups to @charchit , his/her answer was correct!

-teleriffr